# If condition with model in laravel

Tags: if-statement, model, controller, laravel-5.6

Regist Controller:

```
$check = Regist::whereMob($mob)->get();
    if($check == emptyArray()){
        return back()->with('status', 'input error!!');
    }
```

Here i want to return back if $check gets no input.

It produces `(E_ERROR)
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\emptyArray()`

How to check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the way to check empty

```
if ($check->isEmpty()) {...}
```

or

```
if (empty($check)) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks @siva Ganesh your first suggestion works!!        But, I dono why second not worked.

Comment: Let me check it mate